# In PyCharm I enabled FLASK_DEBUG, and FLASK_DEBUG shows = 1,but debug mode still off

Tags: python, flask

In PyCharm I enabled FLASK_DEBUG, and FLASK_DEBUG shows = 1,but debug mode still off

enabled debug
[image: enabled debug]

still debug mode off
[image: still debug mode off]

Answer (score 1):

use `FLASK_DEBUG=True`, I advice you remove the space from the env settings example:

```
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_DEBUG=True
FLASK_RUN_PORT=5000
```

if it does not work then you probably need the pycharm plugin called [EnvFile](https://github.com/Ashald/EnvFile)